# Is head space really necessary when bottling still mead?

Tags: bottling, mead, aging, headspace

I think most of us here leave a head space that is the space left when we pull the wand out of the bottle. So, if we are dealing with still mead is the head space really necessary? Would this space + micro-oxygenation through the cork oxidate much faster long time aged meads? Or is this something we should not concern about?

Comment: "Micro-oxygenation"  - this is something you should not be concerned about as IMHO it is a "non-event".. A space is preferable but only 1 cm or so is needed for thermal expansion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes** the head space is important. At the very least, you need the head space to cushion fluid volume expansion & contraction from temp change.